# Sublime Text 3 PHP Syntax Not Highligting

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sublimetext3

I just started using Sublime Text 3 For Making a web site with HTML5,CSS 3,JavaScript and PHP. All of them works very nicely except PHP.

I uploaded the problem's image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeYxf.png)

Comment: You're working on a PHP page that has HTML in it, so you're gonna get HTML highlighting anywhere you're not inside `<?php ?>` tags. Same can be said for inline `<style></style>` and `<script></script>` tags showing syntax highlighting for CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: the default color scheme in ST3 doesn't color the PHP tags themselves, only their contents.

Comment: Thank you. Yes It is working. I thought that was an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typ into the php block and it will highlight?

[Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNYri.jpg)

Comment: Thanks yes. It is highlight. I though that it must be highlighted like html tags

Comment: No problem, would you vote up for the answer:D? thanx

Comment: I can't I guess I just sign up today. I have not enough points

Comment: No problem, succes with your project